# Why does my Modal.show() function close unexpectedly after a second of being triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, bootstrap-modal

My **Modal.show()** function, specifically: `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: messages});` function is acting very strange. It pops-up displaying a message (`messages`) as designed to, BUT then **mysteriously** closes/vanishes after only a second all by itself.

The intended behavior is for the `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: messages});` **modal** to last long enough for a user to be able to read the contents of the `message`in the **modal**  displayed, then allow for the **modal** to be closed by the user.

Kind someone kindly explain to me why modal triggered by `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: messages});` does not remain open, but closes unexpectedly?

Find below my Template Events code:

```
Template.paymentC2B.events({

'click #payTo'(event, instance) {

        event.preventDefault();

        Meteor.callPromise('c2b', RecipientsProfilePicture ).then(

            function(results) {

           console.log("Results is: " +results);

                if (results == false) {

                    var messages = "Wrong API key, kindly check API key!";

                    Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: messages} ); 

                }
                else {

                }               

           }).catch( function(error) {

           });

});
```

Note that the code `console.log("Results is: " +results);` above will (in the browser console) successfully yield:

```
Results is: False
```

or

```
Results is: True
```

Find below the code to my `Modal` template:

```
<template name="c2bNotifications">
  <div class="modal fade c2bNotifications2">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content modal_c2bNotifications2">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Notification </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">                   
                <div id = approvedMsg > {{msg}} </div>                     
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer c2bNotifications">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="paymentNotificationClose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also find below the packages that are might affect the `Modal`:

```
twbs:bootstrap 3.3.6
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal 1.0.4
```

Comment: Do you have an error message in the console? if so can you edit you post with this message? (Would be easier to understand what is going on)

Comment: @Bastien No error messages are shown in the Console

Comment: does any other modal window is shown autometically after this modal closes?

Comment: @bhagwanparge No, no other modal window displays after the one in subject closes.

Comment: weird do you have a "modal.hide()" event handler somewhere? maybe you can add a debugger point in it a look at the stack trace to understand who calls it. And maybe you can pause on caught exceptions to see if there is one which can cause a modal.hide()

Comment: if you are not able to solve your problem, can you prepare a jsfiddle sample so that others can easily know what is going on.

Comment: You should probably also share the template where your `#payTo` Element appears.